# How to read special characters in java

Tags: java, android

I have this text on a text file which is encoded in UTF-8 `o|▰╹ェ╹|ツ end (◕□◕✿) end ┐(❛△❛；)` when i try to read this in java the output is always like this `?o|??ェ?|ツ end (?□??) end ┐(?△?；)` i even try to encode this in Unicode but still it get the same text here is my code to get print the file

```
File fileDir = new File("src/mycharacters.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF-8"));
String myText = null;
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    myText = line;
}

System.out.print(myText);
```

Comment: You specified to character set as UTF-8 when reading the file, so that should work. But how about System.out? Are you sure it is Unicode-compatible?

Comment: Does the terminal font support the fancy characters you are using?

Comment: okay i see now that the terminal does not support UTF-8 Encoding i write the output file on another text file and it return the text i want thanks MathSquared11235

Answer (score 4):

Your *reading* is fine. Your *writing* is the problem. AFAIK `System.out` has non-UTF encoding on it. Try to wrap it in `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter`:

```
niceOut = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
```

EDIT: Oh wait, maybe @MathSquared11235 is actually correct - I do see ツ in your output, which should indicate UTF output. So... Font.

Comment: If OP copy-pasted it over the font isn't the problem as characters will be moved as-is.

Comment: i used the printstream and try to print just like this niceOut.print(myText) and the output is this "?ｿo|笆ｰ笊ｹ繧ｧ笊ｹ|繝?end (笳補味笳補愾) end 笏?笶帚無笶幢ｼ?"

Comment: In which case, are you sure your file is in UTF-8, and not in, say, EUC-JP or ShiftJIS? (I might be totally wrong here though...)

Comment: MathSquared11235 is correct the terminal does not support UTF-8 i write the output on another text file with utf encoding and it gives me the output i want also thanks for you answer it helps too